# tinymce textcolor plugin does't work on rails 3.x

Tags: plugins, tinymce, textcolor

I'm attempting to run TinyMCE on rails with the standard setup (no gems).  In my init method I am loading a bunch of plugins.  They all appear to be working except the textcolor plugins.  I cannot seem to find any info indicating this is a bug.  No buttons even show up on the menu.  Has anyone attempted to use tiny4.0.2 with the textcolor plugin and had success?  Thanks.

Comment: I just added the emoticons plugin and it does not appear to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Version 4 has made API changes, most plugins are still for version 3.x only. Try the `third party plugin` section on tinyMCE's forum - I know of a truecolor picker-plugin recently made for tinymce4.